# How to refresh text every second in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have to make a countdown timer for which i have written this code. but it is not updating it's UI even after using setState.
I want to refresh remaining time every second.

```
class CustomTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime endtime;
  const CustomTimer({Key? key, required this.endtime}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTimer> createState() => _CustomTimerState();
}

class _CustomTimerState extends State<CustomTimer> {
  Timer? timer;
  Duration remainTime = Duration();

  newTime() {
    // print('hi');
    setState(() {
      final seconds = remainTime.inSeconds - 1;
      remainTime = Duration(seconds: seconds);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    remainTime = widget.endtime.difference(DateTime.now());
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => newTime());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(remainTime.toString().split('.')[0].split('')[0] == '-'
          ? "00:00:00"
          : remainTime.toString().split('.')[0]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually copied this code to DartPad and it shows the countdown in every second.

Comment: This code works correctly for me

Comment: By the way, the `toString()` of a duration doesn't include a `-` when negative, so your logic to stop at 00:00 doesn't work and it just counts up then. You should just do `Text(remainTime.isNegative ? "00:00:00" : remainTime.toString().split('.')[0])`